# How to connect speakers to rpi?

Tags: raspbian, audio, raspbian-stretch, speakers

How to connect this speaker to Raspberry Pi 3 model b+

[image: photo1]
[image: photo2]

I have a PAM8302A amplifier.

Comment: Give us a clue - what connections does it have? Is it amplified? Is it bluetooth?

Comment: I don't know it is amplified. But it haven't bluetooth.

Comment: I assume it is not amplified as it has no power, correct?

Comment: i think it isn't amplified

Comment: Ok, wired connections just looks like a simple speaker. You need to connect an amplifier to the 3.5mm audio/video connector.

Comment: What amplifier?

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at a similar project myself, so I will share what I know.

It looks like it has no power, so you are going to need an amplifier. There are a lot available.  One example (what I have waiting to complete the project) is a simple mono audio one like this one by [adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2130).  It seems to often be recommended that amplifier will need it's own power as well.

Here are some [examples](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ts2012-2-8w-stereo-audio-amplifier/usage-examples) from adafruit to hook up an amplifier.